# What is the anatomy of a ternary operator statement?

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I'm an amateur programmer and is currently trying to learn about recursion. I keep trying to find a website that explains statements such as

```
public static init sumDigits(int i) {
  return i == 0 ? 0 : i % 10 + sumDigits(i / 10);
}
```

and that explains what each individual component does, like the semi-colon or question mark. Help.

Comment: [JLS-15.25. Conditional Operator `? :`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

Comment: The Java code you posted has nothing to do with recursion.  It has to do with the ternary operator.  See Elliott's comment above.

Comment: This post is quite unclear. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

`? :` is a **ternary** operator. In simple words you can say its an **if else** statement.
Now if the condition before `?` is true then the action is the statement written in between `?` and `:`. 
If the condition before `?` is false then the action is the statement written after `:`.

In your case you are mentioning that if `i==0` then return `0` otherwise, return `i % 10 + sumDigits(i / 10)`;

Comment: There are already canonical questions which cover the basics of Java ternary operators.

Answer (score 0):

Let me now narrate this piece of code:

> to compute the sum-of-digits of i first check if i equals 0. If it is,
>   then the result is 0. otherwise the result is the last digit of i plus
>   sum-of-digits of i/10 (rounded down).

- `i == 0` that's "first check if i equals 0"
- `: 0` that's "If it is, then the result is 0"
- `?` that's "otherwise"
- `i % 10` that's "last digit of i`
- `i / 10` that's "i/10 (rounded down)"
- `i % 10 + sumDigits(i / 10)` that's "last digit of i plus sum-of-digits of i/10 (rounded down)"

Answer (score 0):

```
public static init sumDigits(int i) {
  return i == 0 ? 0 : i % 10 + sumDigits(i / 10);
}
```

explanation: First of all correct the return type of the method which is written `init` instead of `int`.

actually the return statement says that,
if the value of `i` is `0` then `return 0` else `return i % 10 + sumDigits(i / 10)`
here `?` determines whether the condition `(i==0)` is true or false. If the condition satisfies(i.e true) then simply return 0 else do some operation with the value of `i`

It could have been written as below:

```
public static int sumDigits(int i) {
          if(i==0)
               return 0;
          else
              return i % 10 + sumDigits(i / 10);
    } // that will result the same as above but with less amount of code.
```